# Template Partial Specialization - any real-world example?

Tags: c++, templates, partial-specialization

I am pondering about `partial specialization`. While I understand the idea, I haven't seen any real-world usage of this technique. `Full specialization` is used in many places in `STL` so I don't have a problem with that. Could you educate me about a real-world example where `partial specialization` is used? If the example is in `STL` that would be superior!

Comment: Sounds like homework ;P

Comment: @Aiden really?! I don't think they allow these things in college!

Comment: @Arak ... I forgot collage is all Java and MSWord .. sorry bout that ;)

Comment: @Aiden, now you are saying the truth :D

Comment: No one taught us MS Word in college. :(

Comment: @jalf, be glad. our teacher told us how to maximize a MS Word window using the mouse.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

C++0x comes with `unique_ptr` which is a replacement for `auto_ptr` which is going to be deprecated.

If you use `unique_ptr` with an array type, it uses `delete[]` to free it, and to provide `operator[]` etc. If you use it with a non-array type, it uses `delete`. This needs partial template specialization like

```
template<typename T>
struct my_unique_ptr { ... };

template<typename T>
struct my_unique_ptr<T[]> { ... };
```

Another use (although a very questionable) is `std::vector<bool, Allocator>` in the standard library. The bool specialization uses a space optimization to pack bools into individual bits

```
template<typename T, typename Allocator = std::allocator<T> >
struct vector { ... };

template<typename Allocator>
struct vector<bool, Allocator> { ... };
```

Yet another use is with `std::iterator_traits<T>`. Iterators are required to define the nested typedefs `value_type`, `reference` and others to the correct types (for a const iterator, `reference` would usually be `T const&`, for example) so algorithms may use them for their work. The primary template uses type-members of the iterator type in turn

```
template<typename T>
struct iterator_traits { 
  typedef typename T::value_type value_type; 
  ...
};
```

For pointers, that of course doesn't work. There is a partial specialization for them

```
template<typename T>
struct iterator_traits<T*> {
  typedef T value_type;
  ...
};
```

Comment: Second point is very interesting... I had no idea, is this part of the standard or compiler specific?

Comment: @DeusAduro, yes it's required by the Standard. It's a common example of a possible misconception, because it makes so `vector<bool>` is not compliant to the container requirements anymore.

Comment: hehe, good old vector<bool>. Lousy design decision, but it *does* illustrate some of the things that are possible with partial specializations.

Answer (score 5):

In some stl implementations collections like `std::vector` and `std::list` use partial template specialization to reduce the amount of code generated for collections of pointers.

Each instantiation of a template for a type T creates new code.  However pointer types are effectively all the same so generating new code for every type is a waste.  This can be reduced by implementing the private part of pointer collections with void pointers and then casting these to the appropriate type in the public interface.  This greatly reduces the code generated for pointer collections.

I think this is covered in Effective STL.

Comment: +1 for the hint to optimize T* (which I could also use in my own template classes)

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about this, but sounds logical. C++ is so cool under the hood... oh wait, it has no hood by design :)

Answer (score 1):

Taken from MSDN (Partial Specialization of Class Templates (C++))

```
// partial_specialization_of_class_templates.cpp
template <class T> struct PTS {
   enum {
      IsPointer = 0,
      IsPointerToDataMember = 0
   };
};

template <class T> struct PTS<T*> {
   enum {
      IsPointer = 1,
      IsPointerToDataMember = 0
   };
};

template <class T, class U> struct PTS<T U::*> {
   enum {
      IsPointer = 0,
      IsPointerToDataMember = 1
   };
};
```

Comment: @Dwefy, I won't downvote your post :) but I am not asking about what is partial-specialization. Thanks...

Comment: but it looks as good sample of partial spec, even more. It injects more types into singular template, allowing you choose what is exactly to specialize